# cannot compile c code to wasm such that it runs on wasm3 on an esp32

Tags: c, esp32, webassembly, arduino-esp32, microprocessors

i am playing around with the wasm3 library for the esp32 and i am trying to load wasm binaries dynamically. what do i mean by that? i want to transmit the binaries via wifi or bluetooth to the esp32 and it automatically deploys it.

i started by studying the fibonacci example provided by the developer:

```
 * Wasm3 - high performance WebAssembly interpreter written in C.
 * Copyright © 2020 Volodymyr Shymanskyy, Steven Massey.
 * All rights reserved.
 */

#include <wasm3.h>

/*
 * WebAssembly app (recursive Fibonacci)
 */

unsigned char fib_wasm[] = {
  0x00, 0x61, 0x73, 0x6d, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x06, 0x01, 0x60,
  0x01, 0x7f, 0x01, 0x7f, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x07, 0x07, 0x01, 0x03,
  0x66, 0x69, 0x62, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x1f, 0x01, 0x1d, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00,
  0x41, 0x02, 0x49, 0x04, 0x40, 0x20, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x0b, 0x20, 0x00, 0x41,
  0x02, 0x6b, 0x10, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x41, 0x01, 0x6b, 0x10, 0x00, 0x6a,
  0x0f, 0x0b
};

/*
 * Engine start, liftoff!
 */

#define FATAL(func, msg) { Serial.print("Fatal: " func " "); Serial.println(msg); return; }
#define TSTART()         { tstart = micros(); }
#define TFINISH(s)       { tend = micros(); Serial.print(s " in "); Serial.print(tend-tstart); Serial.println(" us"); }

void wasm_task(void*)
{
    uint32_t tend, tstart;
    TSTART();

    M3Result result = m3Err_none;

    IM3Environment env = m3_NewEnvironment ();
    if (!env) FATAL("NewEnvironment", "failed");

    IM3Runtime runtime = m3_NewRuntime (env, 1024, NULL);
    if (!runtime) FATAL("NewRuntime", "failed");

    IM3Module module;
    result = m3_ParseModule (env, &module, fib_wasm, sizeof(fib_wasm));
    if (result) FATAL("ParseModule", result);

    result = m3_LoadModule (runtime, module);
    if (result) FATAL("LoadModule", result);

    IM3Function f;
    result = m3_FindFunction (&f, runtime, "fib");
    if (result) FATAL("FindFunction", result);

    TFINISH("Init");

    Serial.println("Running fib(24)...");

    TSTART();

    result = m3_CallV (f, 24);

    TFINISH("Done");

    if (result == m3Err_none) {
        uint32_t value = 0;
        result = m3_GetResultsV (f, &value);
        if (result) FATAL("GetResults: %s", result);

        Serial.print("Result: ");
        Serial.println(value);
    } else {
        M3ErrorInfo info;
        m3_GetErrorInfo (runtime, &info);
        Serial.print("Error: ");
        Serial.print(result);
        Serial.print(" (");
        Serial.print(info.message);
        Serial.println(")");
        if (info.file && strlen(info.file) && info.line) {
            Serial.print("At ");
            Serial.print(info.file);
            Serial.print(":");
            Serial.println(info.line);
        }
    }
#ifdef ESP32
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
#endif
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(100);

    // Wait for serial port to connect
    // Needed for native USB port only
    while(!Serial) {}

    Serial.println("\nWasm3 v" M3_VERSION " (" M3_ARCH "), build " __DATE__ " " __TIME__);

#ifdef ESP32
    // On ESP32, we can launch in a separate thread (with 16Kb stack)
    Serial.println("Running a separate task");
    xTaskCreate(&wasm_task, "wasm3", 16*1024, NULL, 5, NULL);
#else
    wasm_task(NULL);
#endif
}

void loop()
{
    delay(100);
}
```

i tried to reverse engineer the program which he gave in the example (binary is given in the variable fib_wasm) by simply writing a c program and compiling it to wasm via emscriptem. However when i hexdump the generated file with the `xxd` linux command, the produced binary is significantly larger than what he got. Also even if i write a minimal program such as

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

the resulting binary is about 30 times as large.
Also it does not seem to work when i incorporate the generated binary into the program and then modifying accordingly by using

```
    result = m3_FindFunction (&f, runtime, "fib");
    result = m3_CallV (f, 24);
```

I include the binary by running `xxd` on the wasm file, and then formatting it accordingly such that i can paste it into the code.
When running, the output states *Fatal: LoadModule*

has anyone had experience with wasm3 and can help me progress from here?
maybe the wasm program has to have a specific structure or i need a different compiler...
any help would be greatly appreciated:)